# PDO fetch through PHP class variable

Tags: php, class, pdo, while-loop, fetch

Can you explain me why this isn't working? I'm storing PDO fetch into PHP class variable and then I'm trying to loop it using function call.

**PHP class**

```
private $conn;
private $id;
private $data = array();

public function __construct($conn, $id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->loadData();
}

private function loadData() {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindValue(':id', $this->id);
    $sql->execute();

    $this->data = $sql->fetch();
}

public function getData() {
    return $this->data();
}
```

**Script itself**

```
$test = new test($pdo, "100101");

while ($row = $test->getData()) {
    echo $row['item'];
}
```

There will only be loop as long as the memory limit has been reached. Query should return ca. 20 rows only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parameter  `id = :id` and bind `orderId` at `bindValue(':orderId',`

Comment: @Saty: Thanks, it was a typo in my example. Real code doesn't have any typos in code.

Answer (score 0):

1. change `fetch()` to `fetchAll()`
2. change while to `foreach ($test->getData() as $row)`